# Separate MySql tables for registered users and unregistered users

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a practice project its about *Buy & Sell*. I have a confusion about the tables I have in my database for users who are registered with and they have accounts.

My Pencil planning is that a registered user can also Post an ad from their dashboard and an unregistered user can also Post an ad directly without having an account.

My Question is that should I have separate tables like

- `ind_laptops`(ind for independent) = Table for unregistered users for their ads and they can post an ad without having an account; and
- `users_laptop` with `user_id` as a `foreign key` =  Table for users who are registered with us and have accounts they can post right from their accounts dashboard.

I am confuse but i think that its a good practice and can help me a lot in future when filtering the data against per User records.

Comment: I suggest you give more information about how you use the table and the table itself(schema maybe).

Comment: You're right to want both types of user to use one user_id number space.  Which indicates that you're wrong to have two tables.  Whether or not a user is registered should likely be a property of the user (field in a table), not a separate class (table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hold only single table.
Mark unregistered users with id -1 , or create flag field that means whether it is guest post or not.
The reasoning behind it is - that the only difference is if it is registered user or not, the data is the same.

Comment: So you mean that if an unregistered user posts an ad, the foreign key `user_id` will go blank. But if a registered user posts an ad the `user_id` will be populated with his user_id ?

Comment: That makes sense ! Thanks bro